# Multidimensional array can't foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have this array :

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Longline T-Shirt In Fake Linen With All Over Floral Print"
    "price" => 18.11
    "quantity" => 1
    "attributes" => []
    "conditions" => []
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 3
    "name" => "Longline T-Shirt With All Over Aztec Print"
    "price" => 16.99
    "quantity" => 1
    "attributes" => []
    "conditions" => []
  ]
]
```

(dd from laravel)

but when i run foreach on array ($all_order) it returns me only first detail.

tried to flat the array with :

```
$result = [];
        array_walk_recursive($all_order, function($v) use (&$result) {
            $result[] = $v;
        });
        dd( $result);
```

result :

```
 0 => 1
  1 => "Longline T-Shirt In Fake Linen With All Over Floral Print"
  2 => 18.11
  3 => 1
  4 => 3
  5 => "Longline T-Shirt With All Over Aztec Print"
  6 => 16.99
  7 => 1
```

The problem is, i need only id + quantity to down the value of stock from product table.... i'm stack for about 4 hours -_-"

Comment: Where is your foreach code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you have an error in your original foreach code. This is how you'd normally do it:

```
foreach ($all_order as $value) {
  $id = $value['id'];
  $quantity = $value['quantity'];
  // then do something with your values...
}
```